# Code run from Workbook_Open-event aborts with two copies of same workbook open

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which runs when I open a workbook, and until recently it worked fine. The whole thing is rather large, and I am not sure that it is the macro itself which is causing problems, but it aborts on the line `Set ovn3 = Range(startpunkt, sluttpunkt)` in the following codeblock:

```
If fra <= aktivtområde.Cells(aktivtområde.Rows.Count, 1) Then
    Set startpunkt = aktivtområde.Find(What:=DateValue(fra), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, After:=aktivtområde.Cells(aktivtområde.Rows.Count, 1))
    If startpunkt Is Nothing Then
      Set startpunkt = aktivtområde.Cells(1, 1)
    End If
    Set sluttpunkt = aktivtområde.Find(What:=DateValue(til), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, After:=aktivtområde.Cells(aktivtområde.Rows.Count, 1))
    If sluttpunkt Is Nothing Then
      Set sluttpunkt = aktivtområde.Cells(aktivtområde.Rows.Count, 1)
    End If
    Set ovn3 = Range(startpunkt, sluttpunkt)
  End If
```

Trying to print some of the variables used in the codeblock, I can verify that start- and sluttpunkt are valid singlecell ranges, but get the same error when trying reference the range from one to the other:

[image]

Furthermore, when I click on the Excel-symbol in the taskbar to switch between codeview / the workbook, there seems to be two instances of the same workbook open - one in protected and one in "regular" view:

[image]

I suspect this may be the cause of my problems, but I am uncertain how to circumvent it.

My company recently upgraded from Office 2013 to Office 2016 which is when I suspect the issue appeared.

Can anyone here offer any insights on how I may have the code run properly again?

Comment: Kudos to @YowE3K for fixing the problem but I would step through the code and find out at which point you end up with two workbooks open as it sounds like you plugged on leak but another problem is around the corner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should qualify which sheet you are referring to, i.e.

```
Set ovn3 = aktivtområde.Range(startpunkt, sluttpunkt).
```

Without the qualification it may be trying to access a Range on one sheet between two cells which don't exist on that sheet.